# Increasing space between Table View header and cell on storyboared

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios7

I'm migrating my app to iOS 7, what I have notice is that the space between Table View header and cell is small.

- I think this normal behaviour f iOS 7? right.
- I was look better before, Is there away to increase space in static UITableView designed using storyboared.

Comment: Can you add a screenshot to have clearer idea what are you talking about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I think this normal behaviour f iOS 7? right.

**Yes** it is normal behaviour.

> Is there away to increase space in static UITableView designed using
>   storyboard?

[image]

In StoryBoard Select tableview then changing the value under the Attributes Inspector .

Answer (score 0):

For all of them which are not finding @Virus answer useful and if you have dynamic headers height for section follow this method

```
//This method returns the height of a header at a specific section
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    //For example you define heights for these sections
    switch (section)
    {
        case 0:
            return 12.0f;
            break;

        case 1:
            return 23.0f;
            break;

        case 2:
            return 56.0f;
            break;

        case 3:
            return 33.0f;
            break;


        default:
            return 25.0f;
            break;
    }
}
```

Hope it helps